# how to access and display a node.js server side variable in HTML without ejs or AJAX

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

here is my node.js file.In this file i am taking the input of username from 
req.body.userName from the login.html file and the same is storing a variable "user".
now i want to display this user variable in other chat.html file as
"logged in as..... "user"" here user is my node.js server variable.

her is my login.html file

```
 <html><body>
  Username:<br>
    <input type="text" name="userName" required="">
  </body>
  </html>
```

here is my server side code

```
  app.post('/signup', function(req,res){
  if(req.body.userName!=undefined){
   var userDetails = new userModel({
            userName: req.body.userName

        });// end userDetails

        userDetails.save(function(err){
          if(err){
            console.log("user Details are not saved");
          }
          else{
            console.log("user details saved in DB sucessfylly");
            user = userDetails.userName;
            console.log(user);
             res.redirect('/chat');   
          }
        });
      }
      else{
      console.log("please enter user details of all fields")
      }
       });
```

now i want to use this user variable in other chat.html file as a heading as 
"logged in as ..user(ravikota)" for example

please help me by finding the solution Thanks in advance.

Comment: pass it as a parameter in the url like this res.redirect('/chat?name=foo')

Comment: i created a variable user that i am passing as you shown like ('chat/?username=user') it is not working . here username field is an input text field in the chat.html file. should i change it.